# What does Caitlin's father mean in this dialogue?

Tags: dialogue, arrowverse, the-flash

In The Flash season 5 episode 6 Caitlin's father says the following lines.

> I stayed in contact with scientists. Louise Lincoln, Victor Fries, and Harrison Wells. Dr. Wells was able to give me full access to S.T.A.R. Labs video uplink.

Which Dr. Harrison Wells is referred here? Is it the original Dr. Wells or Eobard Thawne (Reverse Flash) version of Dr. Wells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would have been the Eobard Thawne version of Harrison Wells.  Thawne replaced Wells in order to found STAR Labs earlier than it happened originally and cause the early creation of the Flash via the particle accelerator explosion.  Therefore in order to have gotten "full access to STAR" it would have to have been the Thawne version of Wells.

On an unrelated note, Victor Fries who was name dropped is the real name of the Batman villain Mr Freeze who was also a cryogenics specialist...

Comment: Also Louise Lincoln - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killer_Frost#Louise_Lincoln

Comment: And Nora Fries, Victor's wife, is supposed to appear in the incoming cross-over.